# After 12.10, no GUI can authenticate for administration, such as Software Center

Tags: authentication

I upgraded to 12.10, and now I can't use Software Center or Network Administration.  It keeps giving me an authentication errors.  When I check /var/log/auth.log, I see:

```
Oct 31 21:10:45 mike polkit-agent-helper-1[4665]: pam_unix(polkit-1:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=1000 euid=0 tty= ruser=root rhost=  user=root
Oct 31 21:10:51 mike polkit-agent-helper-1[4667]: pam_unix(polkit-1:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=1000 euid=0 tty= ruser=root rhost=  user=root
```

I found a post which said to change my password, which I've done (both through the Ubuntu settings GUI tool, and through recovery mode.  No avail.

Any suggestions?

TIA
M

Answer (score 1):

OK, for whatever reason, ubuntu 12.10 needs a root password set.  You need to:

```
sudo passwd
```

to set your root password (who knew).  After that, things seem to work.